# Conditional division and aggregation

Tags: r, aggregate, division

Consider the following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c("01","02"),
                b = c(100,200),
                c = c(200,400))
```

And the following data frame:

```
agg <- data.frame(d = c("01","01","02","02"),
                  e = c("V1","V2","V1","V3"))
```

I want to change column `a` in `d` using `agg`. That is, if `a = 01` then it should be changed to `V1` and so on. However, in some cases some `a` in `d` goes into multiple names in `e` in `agg`. For instance, both `01` and `02` goes into `V1`. In that case, I want to calculate the average. That is, I want my final dataset this way:

```
    a   b    c    
1   V1  150  300
2   V2  100  200
3   V3  200  400
```

As can be seen, `V1` is an average of `01` and `02`.

How can I do that in **R**?

Comment: The basic logic I imagine would be merge/join on `agg$d`-to-`d$a` - then aggregate the results by `e` after merging.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that as an answer? Sorry, if it seems logical.

Comment: I guess `aggregate(. ~ e,merge(agg, d, by.x = 'd', by.y = 'a'), mean)` should do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boring old base R answer. As commented:

The basic logic would be merge/join on `agg$d`-to-`d$a` - then aggregate the results by `e` after merging.

```
aggregate(cbind(b,c) ~ e, data=merge(agg, d, by.x="d", by.y="a"), FUN=mean)
#   e   b   c
#1 V1 150 300
#2 V2 100 200
#3 V3 200 400
```

In *dplyr* world, the same applies:

```
library(dplyr)
agg %>% 
  left_join(d, by=c("d"="a")) %>%
  select(-d) %>%
  group_by(e) %>%
  summarise_all(list(mean))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  e         b     c
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 V1      150   300
#2 V2      100   200
#3 V3      200   400
```

And *data.table* for good measure:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
setDT(agg)
d[agg, on="a==d"][, lapply(.SD, mean), by=e, .SDcols=-"a"]
#    e   b   c
#1: V1 150 300
#2: V2 100 200
#3: V3 200 400
```

Comment: I get the following error: "invalid type (list) for variable 'e'". My e column is "character" (I assume that is the problem). I cannot change it to "numeric", because it is not numbers. How do I change the "aggregate" code, so it is working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the looks of that error message you have a `list` column for 'e'. Can you do `df$e <- unlist(df$e)` first? It's hard to say without having your actual data.